# Closed /deleted questions, answers, comments repository

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

To improve it in order to ask next better question or supply better answer etc., is there a repository of such items for recycling/re-harvesting ? for back dated references?

Those items that may have been closed/deleted/ mis-posted and so on for whatever reason may still provoke subsequent ( after " thoughts in progress" stage ) remedial thoughts by the asker/answerer/commenter etc. A small part of  what is "junked" may still be lucky for revival to become useful subsequently.

Comment: Closed questions remain available and accessible through a user's profile, at any point while it remains "just" closed.

Comment: For those who can access the moderator tools, via the tab that is viable above a threshold rep, on the review page, one can find deleted questions and answers (and closed questions) up to thirty days post closure/deletion.  (See the "recently deleted" and "recently closed" tabs in the moderator tools hub.)

Comment: Is there a united collection for cross access also?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "cross access".

Comment: Not in the sense that one can be nosy to check and see what posts of an asker or answerer were deleted; at most, that's made available to the specific author of those posts.  The moderator tools are designed to allow users to re-examine closed and deleted posts to see if they can be improved, or should be considered for undeletion.  Only content is listed (title of question, status, because who authored the question or answer has no bearing on whether one should vote to delete/undelete, or close/reopen.

Comment: Can anyone can see others' deleted  items just as in the main area?

Comment: Weird, but my last comment was posted in response to your last comment, Narasimham.

Comment: Again, in  reponse to your last comment.  Only diamond moderators can see deleted questions, answers, and comments on the main areas they once existed.  Else the noise to sound ratio on this site would make valid content on this site "inaudible" and a huge obstacle to navigate for most of us. Any user with over 20K in rep can see deleted answers (faded) in a question's thread.  This is just not feasible to do on the main pages of questions.

Comment: ^^^Actually, I'm not sure that mods see a heavily faded version of deleted questions on the main questions page.  They do see deleted comments and answers where ever they once were.  But for sure they have access to user's deleted questions, likely via the user's profile page.

Comment: Since the moderator tools were mentioned, I'll add that they are available [for 10k+ users](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). The following posts are also somewhat related: [Building an archive of deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122249) (on [meta.se]), and [Stack Overflow Deleted Questions Archive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256638) (on Meta Stack Overflow).

Comment: Since you're a 10k+ user, you can see your own deleted questions: [Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13948) You'll also see deleted questions in various lists. From SEDE you can find links to some deleted posts, but that is a rather clumsy way: [Are there some tools to follow deletions on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28315)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying @MartinSleziak.  I lose track sometimes wrt what privilege is available when.  Thanks for catching my error.  Glad to hear that the use of the mod tools is available to a wider set of users!

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but a screen shot of what the moderator tools landing page looks like, depending on the tab selected there.  Below is the contents of the current Delete tab.  One can check for span of time over which to view posts, up to 30 days, and the downarrows allow one to expand to a larger list of posts in that time frame.  One can also access "recently reopened" and "recently undeleted".

[image]

---

To access the mod tools, click on the upper right hand (background black) icon of a list with a checkmark (review queues).  When you do that, users over 10k in rep will see something like:

[image]

Note the grey box in the upper right of the page: "Tools"

Click on the button to get to a page like the one you see above.