# Avalanche of deletions

Tags: discussion, deletion, 10k-tools

[I expect the point I raise here has been raised before. I searched but didn't find it. Maybe all I need is a pointer to an earlier thread.]

I was looking for a question on which I had recently made a comment. It didn't show up on my Activity tab, so I figured maybe the question had been deleted. So I looked at the list of recent deletions, which listed the 45 most recent deletions. All 45 were said to have been deleted 21 minutes ago!

OK, so that was probably some stackexchange software going through posts and automatically deleting everything it found that met some numerical criteria. I'm not complaining about that, but it makes the "recently deleted" list pretty nearly useless. I wonder whether it couldn't be changed so that the "recently deleted" could, instead of showing a fixed number of deletions, show instead all deletions from, say, the last 24 hours, regardless of the number of deletions during that time period.

Comment: OK, I see this is partly a duplicate of https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28315/are-there-some-tools-to-follow-deletions-on-this-site

Comment: Similar feature requests on [meta.se]: [Improve the “recently deleted” tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/124420) and [Restore the 10k ability to see all closed/deleted posts in a list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92979).

Comment: Where is the list of recent deletions? I don't think I've ever heard of it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos It seems that the OP is talking about the list [available in the 10k-tools](https://math.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last30days).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you. I was not aware of this.

Comment: Way  back then, maybe never on SE, but on early versions of SO, and hence on MO 1.0, there was a complete list. This also had some issues to it but overall I preferred it. In any case I agree that a scope of the list would be better fixed by time rather than some fixed number. Currently in practice the scope is also widely uneven  over sites, e.g., on MESE one can see deletions over almost a month  since there are few. I now actually think there is a cut-off of maybe 30 days in play too.